# Jquery datepicker not working on Laravel application

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datepicker

I am developing a Laravel application. I am trying to have a datepicker on a form. My code is as below
on `layouts.app` file I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

I have also included the scripts file as below on `layouts.app`

```
@yield('content')
    <script  src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script  src="{{ asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
```

On the blade form I have:

```
<input class="datepicker form-control" id="datepicker" type="text">
```

Then in js/custom.js I have a function

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     });
```

The code works fine on jsfiddle, but is not running ok on the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In what way does the code fail?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  In the browser's debugging tools in the network tab, does any of your JavaScript fail to load?  What exactly is happening?

Comment: ```Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function``` is the error on the console

Comment: Look for `defer` in scripts tags or add one to jQuery... Also try change order of scripts or look for new version of it.

Comment: @maki10 thanks. Your solution has solved the problem.

Comment: @BitsAndBytes nice, please vote